# Pandas str.extract and concat columns

Tags: python, pandas, extract

Actually I want to extract info for a `str` col of a dataframe and append this info as new columns, all with piping.

Currently I am doing:

```
(
    pd.DataFrame({'raw': ['name_20200304', 'other_20200305']})
    .pipe(lambda df: pd.concat([df, df.raw.str.extract(r"(?P<name>\w+)_(?P<date>\d{8})")], axis=1))
)
              raw   name      date
0   name_20200304   name  20200304
1  other_20200305  other  20200305
```

but I would expect a more direct way of getting this "extract and append" op.

Comment: Would regex be needed? Split seems to be your way to go

Comment: Yes this is a toy example. But how is the problem different with `str.split` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like :

```
In [53]: pd.DataFrame({'raw': ['name_20200304', 'other_20200305']})
Out[53]:
              raw
0   name_20200304
1  other_20200305

In [54]: df = pd.DataFrame({'raw': ['name_20200304', 'other_20200305']})

In [55]: df[['name','date']]= df['raw'].str.split("_",expand=True)

In [56]: df
Out[56]:
              raw   name      date
0   name_20200304   name  20200304
1  other_20200305  other  20200305
```

Comment: but there is no piping here